# Make a <pre> tag more accessible

Tags: html, accessibility, semantic-markup, screen-readers, pre

In our blog, we're showcasing blocks of code in `<pre>` tags and we want to make them more accessible.

For now, a screen reader would read:

> Here is our code [...]
>   import.org.whatever.i.dont.understand.this.is.too.bad etc

What would be great would be to have a wee announce like:

> Here is our code [...] Block of Java code [...]  > import.org.whatever.i.dont.understand.this.is.too.bad etc

so that the user knows what's going to follow.

How can we do this properly?

Comment: Hmmm I'm not sure how screen readers read figcaptions but this sounds like a perfect scenario for putting a pre in a figure with a figcaption.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> How can we do this properly?

You have to use the HTML5 `code` tag for the Java code, and as you want your website to be accessible for everyone (not only people with screenreaders), type the word Java in the description:

```html
Here is our Java code:
<code>import.org.whatever.i.dont.understand.this.is.too.bad</code>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `<pre>` is okay. `<code>` is good too (needs custom styles for multi-line examples).

To make either accessible, add `aria-label` and `aria-description` attributes:

```html
<pre aria-label="code sample" aria-description="Block of Java code that demonstrates how to blah blah blah.">
  import.org.whatever.now.they.understand
</pre>
```

Here's the minimal CSS to make `<code>` look like `<pre>`:

```css
code {
  display: block;
  font-family: monospace;
  white-space: pre;
}
```

Comment: There is no `aria-description`.  Perhaps you meant `aria-describedby` or `aria-roledescription`?  `aria-describedby` (and `aria-label`) may or may not work on a `<pre>`.  See https://www.w3.org/TR/using-aria/#label-support.  And `aria-roledescription` won't work unless you give the `<pre>` a role.  By default, a `<pre>` has no role (see https://www.w3.org/TR/html-aria/#el-pre) but `aria-roledescription` requires a role (see https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria/#aria-roledescription).  But it's a nice idea and the general principle is good - giving extra explanation to a block of elements.

Comment: @slugolicious
`aria-description` on MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA/Attributes/aria-description

Reflects `ariaDescription`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/ariaDescription

Comment: mozilla doc is pretty decent but is not official.  ARIA 1.1 is the latest accepted documentation from W3.org (not mozilla) and `aria-description` does not exist.  It was added to the **1.3** spec which is still under review but not supported yet, https://w3c.github.io/aria/#substantive-changes-targeted-for-the-1-3-release.  Use of `aria-description` will not work at this time.